# Ajax with jQuery + PHP don´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I pass over the server side(PHP) and the HTML file (script src=blabla... in the head, and div id="rated... in the body).

Function "peticion" works, but after of trigger the function, "like" or "dislike" don´t work, i don´t see any changes in the html.

```
$(function(){


    function like(){
        var asinid = $('#rate').data('id');

        var rHtml = '<a href="#" id="rate" data-id="('+asinid+')" data-action="dislike">No te gusta</a>';


        $('#rated').html(rHtml);   
    }
        function dislike(){
        var asinid = $('#rate').data('id');

        var rHtml = '<a href="#" id="rate" data-id="('+asinid+')" data-action="like">Te gusta</a>';


        $('#rated').html(rHtml);   
    }


    function peticion(e){
        // Realizar la petición
        var parametros = {
            asinid: $('#rate').data('id')
        };


        if ($('#rate').data('action')=='like'){
        var post = $.post("../../likes/addlike.php", parametros, like, 'json');
        }
        else if($('#rate').data('action')=='dislike'){
        var post = $.post("../../likes/dellike.php", parametros, dislike, 'json');
        }

    }

    $('#rate').click(peticion); 
});
```

Function "peticion" works, but after of trigger the function, "like" or "dislike" functions don´t work, i don´t see any changes in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it up a bit since you are using jquery 1.10:

```
var post = $.post("../../likes/addlike.php", parametros, 'json');

post.done(function( data ) {
    like();
  });
```

[jquery post documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

> > The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback methods introduced in jQuery 1.5 are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Also, use `.on` for your dynamically added element:

```
$(document).on('click', '#rate', function(){
     peticion(); 
 });
```

[jquery on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

to get the data value the script will be

```
$('#rate').attr('data-id');
```

use attr method to get any user any attribute value in jquery

Comment: Thanks, i will use it now. But that´s not the problem. Server side works correctly, but i don´t show any change in html side (var rHtml =...)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your event handler

```
$('#rate').click(peticion);
```

destroyed after replacing html code

```
$('#rated').html(rHtml);
```

try to

```
$('#rate').live("click", peticion);
```

or to repeat click() binding after each html()

```
$('#rated').html(rHtml);
$('#rate').click(peticion);
```

Comment: Do not recommend the use of `live` anymore. It was deprecated as of jquery 1.7 and removed in 1.9 which is why it had no effect for @treska since 1.10 is being loaded on the page http://api.jquery.com/live/